# how to bind an alias to a keyboard shortcut in mac?

Tags: shell, zsh, macos

I switch between windows and mac regularly. On windows I can clear the screen with cls, and on mac, I do the same with command+k. I have been trying to find a way to bind cls to command+k. Such that when I type cls in console, it clears the screen. I use zsh.

Answer (score 0):

There's a zle (zsh line editor) widget for clearing the screen and redisplay the prompt and editing buffer: `clear-screen`. By default, it's bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in both the `emacs` and `vi` modes, like in `tcsh` or `bash`, but you can bind it to some other key with:

```
bindkey '^K' clear-screen
```

(in `emacs` mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> is to delete from the cursor to the end of the line, that's a key binding I use very often myself)

If you wanted to implement the `clear-screen` widget by hand, so that it invokes the `clear` command and then redisplay the prompt, you'd create a custom widget such as:

```
myclear-screen() {
  clear
  zle redisplay
}
zle -N myclear-screen
```

Which you could bind the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> with `bindkey '^K' myclear-screen` just the same.

To make a `cls` alias to the `clear` command, the command that clears the screen, you'd do:

```
alias cls=clear
```

Or you could define a `cls` function that invokes the `clear` command with:

```
cls() clear
```

Or:

```
cls() clear "$@"
```

for the arguments you pass to `cls` when invoking it to be passed as-is to `clear`.

You could then make that a zle widget as well with `zle -N cls`, and bind it to a key, but beware that if you invoke it, the screen will be cleared, but your prompt and editing buffer not redisplayed automatically like the `clear-screen` widget does.

Some builtin alternatives to `clear` in `zsh` are:

- `echoti clear` (from the `zsh/terminfo` module, generally loaded by default).
- `echotc cl` (from the `zsh/termcap` module, same command as in tcsh, tc being for termcap while ti for terminfo a slightly more modern terminal capability database).
- `printf %s $terminfo[clear]` where `$terminfo`, also from `zsh/terminfo` is an associate array that maps terminfo termincal capability names (such as `clear`) to the corresponding escape sequence for the terminal identified by `$TERM`.
- `printf %s $termcap[cl]`: termcap equivalent.
- hard code the sequence: on most "modern" terminals the escape sequence that clears the screen and bring the cursor to the top is `\e[H` (to bring the cursor `H`ome), followed by `\e[J` (clear below the cursor). `\e[2J` would clear the whole screen without moving the cursor, `\e[3J` on some would clear the scroll buffer. So:

  ```
  printf '\e[H\e[J\e[3J'
  ```

  would clear everything.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this allows to me to bind another key sequence to clear-screen widget. I would like to alias it to a command. Such that when I write cls in the terminal this widget runs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a Terminal session.
The program `clear` will clear the screen.
You can bind it to `cls` by executing

```
alias cls=clear
```

Put this line in $HOME/.profile to execute in new terminals too

Comment: `~/.profile` is to customise the login session, not the shell. aliases should go in `~/.zshrc` if they are to take effect in all zsh invocations and not just the login ones.

Comment: This does not clear the screen. Only scrolls it downward so they previous content is not visible. You can see the difference on OSX by typing clear and typing command+k